# mongodb spring data Projection project only date component without time component

Tags: mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

mongodb spring data Projection project only date component  remove existing time component.

1. Spring data mongoOperation in which i want to project my date[that is with time] to only date and group on it.
   but i am not able to project it.

That i further need to group data on.

```
   Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(NucleusFunctionSpaceGuestRoomPace.class,
            Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("propertyId").is(propertyId).
                    andOperator(
                            Criteria.where("lastModifiedDate").lt(endDate),
                            Criteria.where("lastModifiedDate").gte(startDate)
                    )),
            sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "propertyId")
                    .and(Sort.Direction.ASC, "bookingId")
                    .and(Sort.Direction.ASC, "roomType")
                    .and(Sort.Direction.ASC, "stayDate")
                    .and(Sort.Direction.DESC, "lastModifiedDate")
            ,
            Aggregation.project().and("propertyId").as("propertyId")
                    .and("bookingId").as("bookingId")
                    .and("roomType").as("roomType")
                    .and("stayDate").as("stayDate")
                    .and("bookingPaceId").as("bookingPaceId")
                    .and("roomNights").as("roomNights")
                    .and("guestRoomStatus").as("guestRoomStatus")
                    .and("lastModifiedDate").as("lastModifiedDate")
                    .andExpression("year(lastModifiedDate)").as("year")
                    .andExpression("month(lastModifiedDate)").as("month")
                    .andExpression("dayOfMonth(lastModifiedDate)").as("month")
        );
```

Comment: Try `.and("lastModifiedDate").dateAsFormattedString("%Y-%m-%d").as("date")`. Note:This output date as string.

Comment: thank you, but can't perform date operation on it, or didn't find a way to make it date again.

Comment: You are welcome. what is your mongo server version ? You can run db.version() in shell to find the version. You can try [`$dateFromString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) in 3.6.

Comment: the mongodb version is 3.4